# Adding a key-value pair to every json element using JOLT v.0.1.1

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I have this JSON input:

```json
{
  "entityType": "job",
  "id": 908815,
  "properties": {
    "AvatureID": 908815,
    "TemplateName": [
      "jicofo package",
      "jitsi meet fork",
      "jitsi-videobridge2 package"
    ],
    "CaseType": [
      "Internal project",
      "Internal project",
      "Internal project"
    ],
    "ProjectType": [
      "Cloud Services",
      "Development",
      "Cloud Services"
    ],
    "Team": [
      "Cloud Operations",
      "Video",
      "Cloud Operations"
    ],
    "Category": [
      "Routine Ops",
      "Platform enhancement",
      "Routine Ops"
    ],
    "WorkflowStepID": [
      "579",
      "531",
      "579"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I need to get this output using a JOLT (v.0.1.1) transformation:

```json
[
  {
    "ParentCaseID": 908815,
    "TemplateName": "jicofo package",
    "CaseType": "Internal project",
    "ProjectType": "Cloud Services",
    "Team": "Cloud Operations",
    "Category": "Routine Ops",
    "WorkflowStepID": "579"
  },
  {
    "ParentCaseID": 908815,
    "TemplateName": "jitsi meet fork",
    "CaseType": "Internal project",
    "ProjectType": "Development",
    "Team": "Video",
    "Category": "Platform enhancement",
    "WorkflowStepID": "531"
  },
  {
    "ParentCaseID": 908815,
    "TemplateName": "jitsi-videobridge2 package",
    "CaseType": "Internal project",
    "ProjectType": "Cloud Services",
    "Team": "Cloud Operations",
    "Category": "Routine Ops",
    "WorkflowStepID": "579"
  }
]
```

But I am having some issues when I try to add the `ParentCaseID`.

I am currently using this JOLT:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "TemplateName": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].TemplateName"
          }
        },
        "CaseType": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].CaseType"
          }
        },
        "ProjectType": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].ProjectType"
          }
        },
        "Team": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].Team"
          }
        },
        "Category": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].Category"
          }
        },
        "WorkflowStepID": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].WorkflowStepID"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And its output is the next one:

```json
[
  {
    "TemplateName": "jicofo package",
    "CaseType": "Internal project",
    "ProjectType": "Cloud Services",
    "Team": "Cloud Operations",
    "Category": "Routine Ops",
    "WorkflowStepID": "579"
  },
  {
    "TemplateName": "jitsi meet fork",
    "CaseType": "Internal project",
    "ProjectType": "Development",
    "Team": "Video",
    "Category": "Platform enhancement",
    "WorkflowStepID": "531"
  },
  {
    "TemplateName": "jitsi-videobridge2 package",
    "CaseType": "Internal project",
    "ProjectType": "Cloud Services",
    "Team": "Cloud Operations",
    "Category": "Routine Ops",
    "WorkflowStepID": "579"
  }
]
```

Is there any modification I can make to that JOLT so I can achieve the results I am looking for?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Mariano, I think no need to hardcode the keys and their respective values one-by-one, rather the `"*":"&"` or `"@":"&"` logic for key-value  match should be considered. Are you able to have a look at my answer as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem when adding the ParentCaseID? I tried the following and it worked:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "TemplateName": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,id)": "[&1].ParentCaseID",
            "@": "[&1].TemplateName"
          }
        },
        "CaseType": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].CaseType"
          }
        },
        "ProjectType": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].ProjectType"
          }
        },
        "Team": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].Team"
          }
        },
        "Category": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].Category"
          }
        },
        "WorkflowStepID": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&1].WorkflowStepID"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Hi. What if `"TemplateName"` array would have zero, one or two components ..?

Comment: Hi @barbarosOzhan, this is not the case. We should have the same quantity of values and it should be always more than one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine those separate objects into single representation as in the following **shift** transformation, and then only pick the single values for the ones with repeated values   *("**ParentCaseID**" array in this case)*  by using **cardinality** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "properties": {
        "AvatureID": { "*": "" }, // this attribute vanishes
        "*": { // else case(all arrays)
          "*": { // the indexes of the respective arrays
            "@2,AvatureID": "[&].ParentCaseID",
            "@": "[&].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // remove duplicated components of the "ParentCaseID"
    // and keep only the single one.
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]